# django.test.Client and response.content vs. streaming_content

Tags: python, django, testing, django-1.6

I have a Django test that accesses a web page using the [Django test client](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/).

In one of the tests, the server returns a ZIP file as an attachment. I access the content of the ZIP file with the following code:

```
zip_content = StringIO(response.content)
zip = ZipFile(zip_content)
```

This causes the following deprecation warning:

> D:/Developments/Archaeology/DB/ArtefactDatabase/Webserver\importexport\tests\test_import.py:1: DeprecationWarning: Accessing the `content` attribute on a streaming response is deprecated. Use the `streaming_content` attribute instead.`

`response.streaming_content` returns some sort of map, which is definitely not a file-like object that's required for `ZipFile`. How can I use the `streaming_content` attribute for this?

Incidentally, I only get the deprecation warning when passing `response.content` to a `StringIO`, when I access the response.content of an ordinary HTML page, there's no warning.

Answer (score 9):

Using Python 3.4.

with String:

```
zip_content = io.StringIO("".join(response.streaming_content))
zip = ZipFile(zip_content)
```

with Bytes:

```
zip_content = io.BytesIO(b"".join(response.streaming_content))
zip = ZipFile(zip_content)
```

Solution found in TestStreamingMixin of https://github.com/sio2project/oioioi/blob/master/oioioi/filetracker/tests.py

See also:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/

You might want to test whether the response is a stream by checking `response.streaming` (boolean).

Answer (score -3):

You should change the approach of your test. The `response.streaming_content` does exactly what it purposes to do. Just test is call to download is ok.

If you want to test file generation/integrity methods, you need to test its feature separately. Doesn't matter if your file is a ZIP or a CSV to Django Test, but if your call to that is ok.

Comment: The purpose of an integration test is to test the call and its result for correctness. It's not sufficient to say the test passes without checking whether the content of the response is correct.